# How do I extract and split coordinates from jQuery values inside brackets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting coordinates via jQuery like this and fill them into a form:

```
$('#location').val(pos);
```

The problem is that the value is filled in like this:

```
(40.00000, 150.00000)
```

How do I extract them from the brackets and "split" them into latitude & longitude values like:

```
pos_lat = 40.00000;
pos_long = 150.00000;
```

Comment: Why not have the form filled like the way you defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ojcoj74y/

```
var pos = "(40.00000, 150.00000)";
var pos_segs = pos.slice(1,-1).split(', ');
var pos_lat = pos_segs[0];
var pos_long = pos_segs[1];
```

UPDATE:

> Thanks! Is it possible to run this within a function, too? –
>   user1996496 1 hour ago

https://jsfiddle.net/ojcoj74y/1/

```
function getPos(strPos) {
  var pos_segs = strPos.slice(1, -1).split(', ');

  return {
    posLat: pos_segs[0],
    posLong: pos_segs[1]
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to run this within a function, too?

Answer (score 2):

Remove brackets and empty space and then split by comma. Finally (if you need) parse strings to floats:

```
positionString.replace(/\(|\)|\s/g, '').split(',')).map(parseFloat);
```